# Why can't Django get the first item in this query set?

Tags: django

I am trying to get one item in a query set but I always get the following error in my view:

```
Tip matching query does not exist.
```

Here is my view code:

```
  tip = None
  if not hole.tip_set.all():
    tip = hole.tip_set.create(content="New")
  else:
    print hole.tip_set.all()
    tip = hole.tip_set.get(pk=1)
```

When I do `print hole.tip_set.all()`, the following prints in my console: `[<Tip: Tip object>]`
But, when I try to "get pk 1", I get the error `Tip matching query does not exist.` This doesn't make sense to me at all. There is clearly an item in the hole's tip_set. Yet, when I try to retrieve it, it says no tips match the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the object's PK is not `1`.

You're looking for `hole.tip_set.all()[0]`.